How to make directory and sub-directories static at once, using express.js
I've a views folder which I made static using app.use(express.static('views')
The views folder contains subdirectories as follows-
views
|-homepage/
|    |-homepage.ejs
|    |-homepage.css
|    |-homepage.js
|
|-partials/
|     |-navbar.ejs
|     |-footer.ejs
|
|-payground/
|    |-playground.ejs
|    |-playground.css
|    |-playground.js

I rendered the homepage and realised that the CSS broke, because I didn't specified the ./views/homepage as static.
Even though it's not a problem right now, because I've onnly limited pages to render, but in future if I decide to create dynamic directories, I've no idea how would I make their particular folders static.
Is there any way, with which I can make a folder static, and all its subdirectories become static too.
I've seen people sayng that once the parent folder is declared static, all its subdirectories become static too which I agree,becasue my homepage.ejs was rendering fine(but without CSS), but, I'm pretty sure, my homepage's css wasn't rendering until I specifically added app.use(express,static('./views/homepage')) to my code.
Thanks in advance!

homepage should be static as well. I guess you provided a wrong path

I'm sorry, I don't get what you are trying to say. But my question is, why do  have to make all the subfolders static, when I already made the parent folder - views static

To serve static files like CSS and JS, it is common to place them in a specific directory, such as public, look at this example.

In your main configuration file (for example, app.js), you need to configure express to serve static files from the public directory:
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
// example route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('homepage/homepage');
});

In your .ejs files, you can include the corresponding CSS and JS files using the correct path to the static files. For example, in homepage.ejs:

I hope it works for you

In order to get the files in sub-directories referenced, the URL path should be relative to the root in express.static.
The below code will work since the url path in the link is relative to root.
//server.js
app.use(express.static('views'));

//homepage.ejs
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/homepage/homepage.css" />

The below code will fail to load the css file since the url path is not relative.
//homepage.ejs
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/homepage.css" />

However the below code will work since there are multiple directories to server static files and the root in the second express.static call will serve the file referenced.
//server.js
app.use(express.static('views'));
app.use(express.static('views/homepage'));

//homepage.ejs
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/homepage.css" />

